# Java return from function when variable gets assigned a certain value

Tags: java

Is it possible to leave a function if a variable (inside the function) gets asssigned a certain value at any point. For example:

```
public class TestClass {
    public int doSomething() {
        int resultCode;
        
        resultCode = checkFirstThing() //Returns 0 if succeed or 1 if not
        //Exit if resultCode != 0
        
        resultCode = checkSecondThing() //Returns 0 if succeed or 2 if not
        //Exit if resultCode != 0

        resultCode = checkThirdThing() //Returns 0 if succeed or 3 if not
        //Exit if resultCode != 0

        //do Something if all clauses succeeded

        return resultCode
    }
}
```

My problem is, that I don't want to add a `if(resultCode != 0) return resultCode` after each Check-Function.
I didn't find anythig myself, but as there are some very smart heads out there, I thought that mybe someone else knows a better way than my curren solution (guard clauses after each check).

I know what I want is propably not possible, but this Question is here to make sure.

Tanks for your help :)

Comment: You can combine the if and assignment together: `if ((resultCode = checkFirstThing()) != 0) return resultCode;` Not sure if you like it...

Comment: How about you add each result code and finally check if it is 0? if 0, all success, else at least one of it failed. I won't recommend it though since it affects readability.

Comment: And why you don't want to add  `if(resultCode != 0) return resultCode` ?

Comment: Or add the `check*()` methods to a `List` (either method references or wrapped inside `Runnable`s. Then `int resultCode; for (int i = 0; i < methods.size(); i++) { resultCode = methods.get(i).run(); if (resultCode != 0) { return i; } return resultCode;`

Comment: @SudhirOjha Because I'd have to repeat myself several times. I don't like duplicate code and I thought maybe there's a better way to do that.
I currently am using the guard clauses :)

Comment: @jensgram interesting approach! Thanks for the idea, even tho it might make the code pretty unreadable.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the if-statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a higher order function for this. You essentially just want to get the result code of the first check that isn't 0, or 0 if all checks returned 0.

```
public static int checkAll(IntSupplier... resultCodeSuppliers) {
    return Arrays.stream(resultCodeSuppliers)
        .mapToInt(IntSupplier::getAsInt)
        .filter(x -> x != 0)
        .findFirst().orElse(0);
}
```

This works because stream operations are lazy. When I do `findFirst`, it will only run the checks that return 0, plus the first check that returns non-0. It won't run any more checks after that one, because I only asked it to `findFirst`.

Usage:

```
int resultCode = checkAll(
    () -> checkFirstThing(),
    () -> checkSecondThing(),
    () -> checkThirdThing()
);
if (resultCode == 0) { // you only need this one check
    // do the thing...
}
return resultCode;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I had to update my question because of a misthinking on my side. But this answer would have solved the initioal question.

Comment: @DragonCoder [The general rule is that your edit is not supposed to invalidate existing answers. If your edit does that, please post a new question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281463/5133585)

Comment: Thanks for the info :)
WIll do exactly that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.OptionalInt` of Java 8.

```java
public class TestClass {
    public int doSomething() {
        return OptionalInt.of(checkFirstThing())
            .map(x -> x != 0 ? x : checkSecondThing())
            .map(x -> x != 0 ? x : checkThirdThing())
            .getAsInt();
    }
}
```

However, comparisons to zero are unavoidable since you need boolean values instead of int values whatsoever.
Maybe you can create a wrapper function for the comparison to zero and use `OptionalInt.empty()` to avoid the ternary operators.

Answer (score 1):

One way that suddenly now, came to my mind is that you can make your methods to `return 1` if operation succeed or **`throw a exception`** otherwise.

then you can put all your calls to methods inside a `try...catch` and then if any exception occur you simply return from `catch` statement.

good luck :)

---

```java
public class TestClass {
    public int doSomething() {
        int resultCode;
        
        try {
            resultCode = checkFirstThing(); //Returns 1 if succeed
            //Exit if exception thrown

            resultCode = checkSecondThing(); //Returns 1 if succeed
            //Exit if exception thrown

            resultCode = checkThirdThing(); //Returns 1 if succeed
            //Exit if exception thrown
        } catch (/* kind of your exception */) { return 0; /* failure */ }

        //do Something if all clauses succeeded

        return resultCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to have a result object (implemented in its own class). This object consists of a code, which is set by the called methods (like checkFirstThing), if the check is successful. The object furthermore contains a flag or another information, whether the check is successful at all, which is also set by your methods checkXXThings.
That way you do not mingle stuff like transactions, null checks, exceptions with your logic, which would be bad for readability and couples technical issues with process logic. The code is NOT shorter than your first idea to do a null check (since you do have to check the success flag), but more concise and expresses, what you want to check. The solution form @Naetmul does essentially the same (as long as you return an Optional.empty() for a failed checkXXThings method call).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `checkX` methods to return a `boolean` (`true` for success, `false` for failure), and move the error codes to the method that calls them (`doSomething()`):

```
public int doSomething() {
    if (!checkFirstThing()) {
        return 1;
    } else if (!checkSecondThing()) {
        return 2;
    } else if (!checkThirdThing()) {
        return 3;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the framework of Spring to solve this situation. @see

[spring.io](https://spring.io/)

And using the annotation in which named @transactional  on the method. It can lead to the method process success if all submethod return success without exceptions. Otherwise, It can lead to rollback the method process.