# Java return from function when variable gets assigned a certain value FOLLOW UP

Tags: java

This is a FollowUp-Question to [my first Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67465486/java-return-from-function-when-variable-gets-assigned-a-certain-value)
Is it possible to leave a function if a variable (inside the function) gets asssigned a certain value at any point. This time with actions between the assignments. For example:

```
public class TestClass {
    public int doSomething(Message message) {
        int resultCode;
        
        resultCode = checkFirstThing(message) //Returns 0 if succeed or 1 if not
        //Exit if resultCode != 0
        
        //do something with message

        Permission perm = message.author.perm

        resultCode = checkSecondThing(perm) //Returns 0 if succeed or 2 if not
        //Exit if resultCode != 0

        //Excecute something

        resultCode = checkThirdThing() //Returns 0 if succeed or 3 if not
        //Exit if resultCode != 0

        //do Something if resultCode still 0
        return resultCode
    }
}
```

My problem is, that I don't want to add a `if(resultCode != 0) return resultCode` after each Check-Function, because it would be duplicate code.

Tanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often in OOP, if you do not want to duplicate code, you design a class for it. In this case it is applicable, too.

Let's start with

```
public class Result {

    private int code;

    public Result(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return 0 == code;
    }

}
```

Accordingly, you retrofit your other methods to return an instance of `Result` instead of a primitive `int`.

```
public Result checkFirstThing(/* parameters */) {
    // implementation
}

public Result checkSecondThing(/* parameters */) {
    // implementation
}

...
```

At this point we have not gained much, the `doSomething` method would look roughly the same. However, look at the following method for the `Result` class

```
public Result and(Supplier<? extends Result> code) {
    return isSuccess() ? code.get() : this;
}
```

This method essentially performs a lazy AND conjunction between itself and the specified portion of code that was passed in as a `Supplier`.

More formally, if this `Result` denotes a successful outcome, the specified code will be executed and its result will be returned. If otherwise, this `Result` denotes a faulty outcome, the specified code will not be executed and this `Result` will simply return itself.

You can now use this method to chain your method calls together without adding any `if` statements.

```
public int doSomething(Message message) {
    Result result = checkFirstThing(/* parameters */)
         .and(() -> checkSecondThing(/* parameters */))
         .and(() -> checkThirdThing(/* parameters */));
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        /* 
         * Do your actual processing. You could also add your main processing 
         * to the method chain above, but I think like this it is more clear
         * for future reading.
         */
    }
    return result.getCode();
}
```

---

**Addressing in-between statements**

I'm not that big of a fan of side-effects or any statements in between longer method chains. In your example, however, you simple access a field in your model, so let's see how this would look like as an intermediate operation

```
Message message = null;
// iniialize message
Result result = checkFirstThing(message).and(() -> {
    Permission perm = message.author.perm;
    return checkSecondThing(perm).and(() -> checkThirdThing(perm));
});
```

If find this much less readable than simply having copied `Permission perm = message.author.perm` into the respective `check...` methods.

Having all the check methods being based on an instance of `Message` also makes them more concise, because they are all based on the same (type of) input, so for future reading one can quickly assess the contract of all methods at the same time. If, otherwise, some methods are based on `Message` and some are based on `Permission`, future readers will have to "decrypt" the above method chain in order to understand which permission of the message is being evaluated.

However, to get back some redability at this point, you can extract the inner part of the method chain to a new method

```
private Result checkAuthorPermissions(Message message) {
    Permission perm = message.author.perm;
    return checkSecondThing(perm).and(() -> checkThirdThing(perm));
}
```

and simply do

```
Result result = checkFirstThing(message)
     .and(() -> checkAuthorPermissions(message));
```

Comment: At first wow this is an interesting piece of code! I love to learn new things an this definetly is.  But as I aked below the first Answer: How would it work if I'd want "normal" code between these Check-Methods. Like what if I'd need to save something between `checkFirstThing` and `checkSecondThing`?

Comment: @Izuro Thank you very much! This works perfektly well. Because you said  `"In your example, however, you simple access a field in your model"`, what would you change if I'd do something else there, like Calling an API(not what I do, but I'm interested :D)?

Comment: Code-wise, there are no changes. If you have side-effects (e.g. by calling some API that changes your underlying model), then these side-effects will simply apply to the following execution, which may be hard to follow. More critically, these side-effects will not apply, if some previous evaluation fails, so any following code must be aware of these *optional* side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
class SomethingException extends Exception {
    public final int resultCode;
    SomethingException(int resultCode) {
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
    }
}

void checkResultCode(int resultCode) throws SomethingException {
    if (resultCode != 0)
        throw new SomethingException(resultCode);
}

public int doSomething(Message message) {
    try {
        checkResultCode(checkFirstThing(message));
        //Exit if resultCode != 0            
        //do something with message          
        Permission perm = message.author.perm;
        checkResultCode(checkSecondThing(perm));
        //Exit if resultCode != 0
        //Excecute something
        checkResultCode(checkThirdThing());
        //Exit if resultCode != 0
        //do Something if resultCode still 0
        return 0;
    } catch (SomethingException e) {
        return e.resultCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to do something between the Check-Methods?

Comment: This looks like it'll work, thanks. Definetly will try that out when I'm back home. Will accept it then.

Comment: I don't think exceptions are the most concise approach here. Exceptions are meant to model exceptional return states, not to evaluate preconditions. I have added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67466904/7525132) showing an alternative approach.

Comment: @saka1029 This works fine, thanks. But I have to agree with Izuro. Still a nice working approach